# loading regions of textureatlas in libgdx loads the entire file

Tags: libgdx

I managed to pack a textureatlas with images i have and it works properly in that it creates the .pack file and the .png file. The issue is when i load the texture atlas and try to assign  AtlasRegions. it loads the entire atlas instead of only the image i want. here is a mockup code i used to test it.

```
@Override
public void create() {      
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(800, 480);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    test = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("polytest.png"));

    sprite = test.findRegion("hero");
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);


}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(sprite.getTexture(), 10, 10);
    batch.end();
}
```

this renders the entire atlas instead of only the image called "hero" in the atlas. Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do.-

```
batch.draw(sprite.getTexture(), 10, 10);
```

you're actually telling `libgdx` to render the whole `Texture`. What you need is to draw just the `TextureRegion`.-

```
batch.draw(sprite, 10, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i have been slaving over this whole weekend! cant believe it was so simple :O