# TextureRegion Loads Whole TextureAtlas in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to load a TextureRegion from my TextureAtlas. However, it's loading the whole TextureAtlas instead of just the subimage.

The issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774201/loading-regions-of-textureatlas-in-libgdx-loads-the-entire-file) but I'm not calling sprite.getTexture(), yet I'm getting the same problem.

```
TextureAtlas atlas;     
oceanTextureRegion; 

atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("atlas.txt"));
oceanTextureRegion = atlas.findRegion("ocean");
```

in render method...

```
batch.draw(oceanTextureRegion, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `atlas.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you have wrong region uv scale & position in **atlas.txt** pack file, or you have changed the `oceanTextureRegion` UV position to larger values, notice if you change UV Position of region then it takes other part of images.