# Loading correct texture from Atlas with multiple pages

Tags: java, libgdx, texturepacker, texture-atlas

I have a big set of images saved in one atlas, but due to the 2048*2048 size limitation of a single page I had to split my packs in 12 pages.

My problem is that when I use  `atlas.findRegion(imageName).getTexture()` to load the texture, it loads the whole 2048*2048 page and not the single texture inside the page (the image pack contains the correct image though, so I know it's loading the correct file, I just don't understand why it's not cropping the texture around the image I pass as parameter to findRegion).

Thanks in advance, hope the question is detailed enough to receive an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually calling the `getTexture()` method, I just needed to load the Region. More info here [loading regions of textureatlas in libgdx loads the entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774201/loading-regions-of-textureatlas-in-libgdx-loads-the-entire-file)